# Change register form action url

Tags: login, urls, forms, user-registration

I have 2 registration forms, default one on `/wp-login.php?action=register` for "recruiter" users, other one on `/wp-login.php?action=register&type=candidat` for "candidates" users

My problem is that on candidate form, the form tag still has `/wp-login.php?action=register` as the action URL, and I want it to be `/wp-login.php?action=register&type=candidat`

I tried updating wp-login.php file but if I update Wordpress in the future, my code will be overwritten

I've tried other topics recommanding to use 'register_url' hook but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<?php

add_action( 'register_form', function() {
    $get_type = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    if ( ! $get_type ) {
        return;
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $get_type ); ?>" />
<?php
});
```

This will add the `type` parameter as a hidden field on the form if it is set in the GET query string.

Comment: Thanks, you made me realize that I already had a hidden input with the type, but wasn't using it correctly !

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route than the other answer, a modification of the registration URL through the site_url filter, I've tested it, and it works.

```
function my_verify_registration_type( $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id ) {
    if ( $scheme == 'login_post' ) {
        if ( strpos( $url, '?action=register' ) !== false && !empty( $_REQUEST['type'] ) ) {
            $url = esc_url( add_query_arg( 'type', sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['type'] ), $url ) );
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'site_url', 'my_verify_registration_type', 10, 4 );
```